# Unable to start Bluemix application

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I have created a small node.js application and deployed it on Bluemix. But I am unable to start the application. It gives the following error:

```
An instance of the app crashed: failed to accept connections within
health check timeout. exit status : 1, CRASHED.
```

Sometimes the application starts, but it stops automatically within seconds.

Can someone help?

Regards

Aniz

Comment: There can be many reasons that an application will crash.  You will need to get log files by executing `cf logs <appname> --recent` with the cf-cli tool.  Paste some of the log entries into your question to provide more context so that we can assist.

Answer (score -1):

In the past two days an intermittent problem occurred in Bluemix platform, and this might be the cause of the crash. Let us know if you still experience the problem.